# Create a new workbook and paste data 3 different workbooks one after the other

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question (incidentally I have multiple questions, which will be posted later) regarding Creating a new workbook and paste data 3 different workbooks one after the other.

This is a part of daily routine, where concerned people will be posting 3 different sets of data in 3 different folders. File names will be given based on date. Example: My book 01 22, NT book 01 21 etc.

Instead of manually taking each file and copying data into one single sheet, I want to use a Macro to create a new workbook, save it as per the date and copy data from the 3 different workbooks stored in different folders, one after the other in one single sheet.

Below is the code I am using:

```
Sub Main()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim SelectedItem As Variant

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd

.AllowMultiSelect = True


If .Show = -1 Then

For Each SelectedItem In .SelectedItems

Workbooks.Open (SelectedItem)
    'Workbooks.Application.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
    Workbooks("NewBook").Activate
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    MsgBox (LastRow)
    NewBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    MsgBox (LastRow)
Next SelectedItem
End If
End With

Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I have updated my query with the code. Also, each workbook contains single sheet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the macro recorder (http://m.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-record-a-macro-to-automate-tasks-in-excel-2.html). It simply reproduces the steps you do manually in Excel as VBA-Code. You can use that as a first step if you dont know much about VBA. Look at the code and try to alter it. I often use it if I dont know the VBA Commands for standard Excel Features.